# what happens to old views when a new view is created in MVC

Tags: javascript, backbone-views

what happens to old views when a new view is initiated in backbone m-v-c framework?
the view object will be there in DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your question is, what happens when a new view is loaded **in place** of an old view, is it removed ? or is it just hidden  using CSS?

Answer is, the Old view is simply replaced by New view in the `Dom`, so old view is not there in the `Dom`.